# NoActionBar сверху добавил белую полоску

Tags: android, kotlin, android-style

Всем доброго времени суток. Тяжело объяснить, но в манифесте для определенной сцены прописал `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` и ActionBar убрался, но появилась другая проблема, теперь сверху где показано "Время", "Открытые приложения", "Уровень связи" и другие иконки, задний фон белый, а нужен например colorPrimary

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

[image: Собственно вот]

А надо вот так:

[image: Вот так]

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что это поможет вам:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:


    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window


    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color


        window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```